# Do convex bodies that are not polytopes have infinitely many extreme points?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

A little silly question: if $A$ is a convex body and $A$ is *not* a convex polytope, does this mean that the number of extreme points of $A$ is infinite?

Comment: How about a single point? Is it a polytope?

Comment: I think by the definition, it is~~~

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an entirely silly question, not even in the planar case. Let me give the argument in the plane; a higher dimensional argument works too.

Suppose the number of extreme points of $A$ is a finite set $P$ having $\ge 2$ points. The set $A$ is the convex hull of $P$, meaning the intersection of all convex closed sets containing $P$. With some work (by induction on the cardinality of $P$), one can show that $A$ is the intersection of the finite set of closed half-planes $H$ having the property that $P \subset H$ and $P \cap \partial H$ contains at least two points. From this description it then follows, with some more work, that $A$ is a convex polygon.